# How can I filter out rows in my Influx table with a certain column value occurring more than once?

Tags: filtering, unique, influxdb

Say I have a simple Influx input table that looks like this:

| _measurement | _time | my_var |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x | time_1 | a |
| x | time_2 | b |
| x | time_3 | b |
| x | time_4 | c |
| x | time_5 | d |
| x | time_6 | d |
| x | time_7 | e |

And I want to end up with an output table that looks like this:

| _measurement | _time | my_var |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x | time_1 | a |
| x | time_4 | c |
| x | time_7 | e |

You'll notice that all the rows in the input table that had a value in the my_var column that occurred more than once, was filtered out. Notice also, even if the row was not unique (on my_var) all those are removed completely. Thus "b", "d" does not exist anymore.

I've scanned through lots of the Flux functions like group(), unique(), count(), distinct() etc. but could not find a way to achieve this. These functions remove duplicates, but they always keep a unique row remaining.  It surely has something to do with uniqueness and seems like a trivial kind of thing to be able to do... :)

My platform is: InfluxDB OSS ver 2.7

Any help will be sincerely appreciated!